# Drawbacks when using undefined constants as variables

Tags: php, constants

Huh, don't know what to search for, therefore have no idea if this is a duplicate or not.

Example:

```
function foo($bar){
    switch($bar)
        case UNDEFINED:
            return 'foo';
        break;
        case DEFINED:
            return 'bar';
        break;
        default:
            return 'no foo and no bar';
    }
}

echo foo(DEFINED); # edited: had $ before function call
// bar

echo foo(OUTPUT);
// no foo and no bar
```

PHP (version 5.3) doesn't throw any errors, but are there any drawbacks to this?

Comment: How does this work?  I don't think this is doing what you think it does.  What values are DEFINED and UNDEFINED set to?

Comment: @Nathan, well, it does work and it does what I think it does.

Comment: @Tom which is what?  It's not at all clear from your question.  As @spektom says below, it's comparing $bar == "UNDEFINED" and $bar == "DEFINED", if you haven't defined those constants.  If you have defined those constants, then it is comparing them to whatever values you've set them too.

It is not checking to see if they're defined or undefined, which the code implies (though I'm not sure if you do).

Comment: @Nathan, huh, those aren't defined (at all), and, so it turns them into a string, then compares. Basicly, temporary constants to represent a variable without $. Have I made myself clear now? *does exactly what spektom's answer depicts*

Comment: Did you define those constants somewhere else.?

Comment: Yes, you're just doing a (not recommended) string compare.  Why not put them in double quotes?  That way, it won't break if you or someone else ever defines those constants and will explicitly show in code what you're trying to compare.  There is no advantage to using the deprecated "undefined constant string syntax" and plenty of danger.

Comment: @Nathan, aware of all that now and fixed it all. And yes, was asking just to know if it's ok/not to use it that way. Just a random quote about danger: "Where there is danger, there is opportunity!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undefined constants are interpreted as strings. In your case these would be two strings "DEFINED" and "UNDEFINED". From the PHP manual:

> If you use an undefined constant, PHP
>   assumes that you mean the name of the
>   constant itself, just as if you called
>   it as a string (CONSTANT vs
>   "CONSTANT"). An error of level
>   E_NOTICE will be issued when this
>   happens.

**EDIT** Ignoring `E_NOTICE` is considered to be *bad style*, this is from PHP documentation:

> Enabling E_NOTICE during development
>   has some benefits. For debugging
>   purposes: NOTICE messages will warn
>   you about possible bugs in your code.
>   For example, use of unassigned values
>   is warned. It is extremely useful to
>   find typos and to save time for
>   debugging. NOTICE messages will warn
>   you about bad style. For example,
>   $arr[item] is better to be written as
>   $arr['item'] since PHP tries to treat
>   "item" as constant. If it is not a
>   constant, PHP assumes it is a string
>   index for the array.

Comment: And besides E_NOTICE error, there are no other drawbacks and I can freely use it? Or it's not recommended?

Comment: Ah, I see... Basicly `foo(UNDEFINED_CONSTANT)` is kind of like `$array[UNQUOTED_KEY]`?

Comment: Yes, in both cases PHP **silently** converts uninitialized constant to a string.